# How do you format Python using json.dumps, to make your Lambda function respond correctly to API Gateway?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

This is my first post on Stack Overflow, so hope I'm being specific enough. I am trying to integrate a Lambda function (coded in Python) with DynamoDB and API Gateway. I want the API to return a single item from DynamoDB, but I'm getting an `Internal server error` message when I navigate to the API endpoint. I have looked at the CloudWatch Logs and they say it's caused by a `malformed Lambda proxy response`.

Having further investigated, I am fairly sure this has to do with formatting the Lambda `responseBody` using `json.dumps`. But I don't know the correct syntax to do this having tried dozens of different combinations (I don't have any Python experience).

Here is my Lambda function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    ddbResponse = table.update_item(
        Key={
            "id": "user1"
        },
        UpdateExpression='ADD clicks :inc',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':inc': 1
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )

    responseBody = json.dumps(XXXXXXXXXX)

    apiResponse = {
        "isBase64Encoded": False,
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": responseBody
    }

    return apiResponse
```

If I just want the API response to be the number of `clicks` returned from the DynamoDB table, what would I have to put in the XXXX's between the `json.dumps` bracket? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ddbResponse['Attributes']['clicks'])` will give you clicks. we can return

```
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps({'clicks': int(ddbResponse['Attributes']['clicks'])})
}
```

To return only clicks

```
{
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': int(response['Attributes']['clicks'])
}
```

Comment: thanks Balu! That's really helpful. One additional question, is it possible to get only the digit returned in the response? 

The above returns ```{"clicks": 50}```, but if I just wanted to return ```50```, is there a way?

Comment: @fhoskyns we can remove json.dumps and return just a string/number too. i just edited the answer with additional block.

Comment: that's amazing, thanks @Balu Vyamajala! so json.dumps was not even required after all?

Comment: json.dumps is just used to convert an json object to a string!